# Mysterious line breaks in table

Tags: html, line-breaks

[UPDATED]. I have a table nested within another that was working fine until one day it appeared half way down the page. I checked the actual file which is fine:

```
<div align="center">
<table width="630" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" style="background-color:white;">
<tr>
<td>
<table width="630" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
```

When I view the page source, same thing:

```
<div align="center">
<table width="630" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" style="background-color:white;">
<tr>
<td>
<table width="630" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
```

But when I inspect element on chrome it shows the following:

```
<div align="center">
<table width="630" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" style="background-color:white;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<table width="630" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
```

Full code for the table is below:

```
<div align="center" class="tabContent" id="imminent">
<br>

<table width="630" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0"  style="border-collapse:collapse" >
<tr>
<td>
<table width="630" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">


<br>
<div align="center">
<table width="630" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" style="background-color:white;">
<tr>
<td>
<table width="630" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">

<tr>
<td width="65" align="center"><label class="desc" id="title1" for="date">Date</label></font></td>
<td width="20" align="center"><label class="desc" id="title1" for="state">ST</label></font></td>
<td width="195" align="center"><label class="desc" id="title1" for="practice_name">Name</label></font></td>
<td width="70" align="center"><label class="desc" id="title1" for="status">Returned</label></font></td>
<td width="70" align="center"><label class="desc" id="title1" for="progress">Sent Info</label></font></td>
<td width="70" align="center"><label class="desc" id="title1" for="progress">F/U 2</label></font></td>
<td width="70" align="center"><label class="desc" id="title1" for="edit">F/U 3</label></font></td>
<td width="70" align="center"><label class="desc" id="title1" for="edit">F/U 4</label></font></td>
</tr>

<?php
while($rowsim=mysql_fetch_array($resultim)){


$var1im = '<abbr title="Completed on: '.$rowsim['sentdate'].'">'.$rowsim['sentinfo'].'</abbr>';
$var2im = '<abbr title="Completed on: '.$rowsim['follow2date'].'">'.$rowsim['follow2'].'</abbr>';
$var3im = '<abbr title="Completed on: '.$rowsim['follow3date'].'">'.$rowsim['follow3'].'</abbr>';
$var4im = '<abbr title="Completed on: '.$rowsim['follow4date'].'">'.$rowsim['follow4'].'</abbr>'; }

?>

<tr>
<td width="65">&nbsp;&nbsp;<? echo $rowsim['date']; ?></td>
<td width="20">&nbsp;<? echo $rowsim['state']; ?></td>
<td width="195">&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="webleads.php?id=<? echo $rowsim['id'];?>"> <? if($rowsim['name']!="") {echo $rowsim['name']; } else { echo $rowsim['office']; }?></a></td>
<td width="70">&nbsp;<? echo $rowsim['returned']; ?></td>
<td width="70">&nbsp;<? echo $var1im; ?></td>
<td width="70">&nbsp;<? echo $var2im; ?></td>
<td width="70">&nbsp;<? echo $var3im; ?></td>
<td width="70">&nbsp;<? echo $var4im; ?></td><br>
</tr>

<? } ?>

</table>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br />
</div>

</table>
</table>
</div>
```

Only Javascript code I'm using is to make tabbed pages. Worked great for quite a while until this happened.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

var tabLinks = new Array();
var contentDivs = new Array();

function init() {

  // Grab the tab links and content divs from the page
  var tabListItems = document.getElementById('tabs').childNodes;
  for ( var i = 0; i < tabListItems.length; i++ ) {
    if ( tabListItems[i].nodeName == "LI" ) {
      var tabLink = getFirstChildWithTagName( tabListItems[i], 'A' );
      var id = getHash( tabLink.getAttribute('href') );
      tabLinks[id] = tabLink;
      contentDivs[id] = document.getElementById( id );
    }
  }

  // Assign onclick events to the tab links, and
  // highlight the first tab
  var i = 0;

  for ( var id in tabLinks ) {
    tabLinks[id].onclick = showTab;
    tabLinks[id].onfocus = function() { this.blur() };
    if ( i == 0 ) tabLinks[id].className = 'selected';
    i++;
  }

  // Hide all content divs except the first
  var i = 0;

  for ( var id in contentDivs ) {
    if ( i != 0 ) contentDivs[id].className = 'tabContent hide';
    i++;
  }
}

function showTab() {
  var selectedId = getHash( this.getAttribute('href') );

  // Highlight the selected tab, and dim all others.
  // Also show the selected content div, and hide all others.
  for ( var id in contentDivs ) {
    if ( id == selectedId ) {
      tabLinks[id].className = 'selected';
      contentDivs[id].className = 'tabContent';
    } else {
      tabLinks[id].className = '';
      contentDivs[id].className = 'tabContent hide';
    }
  }

  // Stop the browser following the link
  return false;
}

function getFirstChildWithTagName( element, tagName ) {
  for ( var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++ ) {
    if ( element.childNodes[i].nodeName == tagName ) return element.childNodes[i];
  }
}

function getHash( url ) {
  var hashPos = url.lastIndexOf ( '#' );
  return url.substring( hashPos + 1 );
}

//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Your HTML is _quite_ invalid. Where are all the closing tags?

Comment: Post your javascript code.<br/> May be added from some client side script.

Comment: This is just the opening tags (only where the issue is). I'll add the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Inspection of the current page differs from the page source (obviously). Each browser interprets the code that's requested. The source shows what the browser receives, inspection shows the interpretation.

One of the things Chrome (and possibly other browsers) do nowadays, is trying to improve the code, by bringing it up to standard. You probably did not define a different (X)HTML document type in your page, so it completed your code by adding `tbody`. Interpretations will also (try to) fix errors, like typos and missing closing tags.

I can't reproduce the linebreaks: can you add your complete code for that?

Update: Still can't reproduce the linebreaks. It must have something to do with PHP. You might want to close the `tr` and `td` of the outer two tables as well... Maybe PHP doesn't like that.